# Realm SyncConfiguration.Builder deprecated

Tags: android, realm

I am using Realm Cloud Sync and I used to write following code for logging in to server.

```
if (SyncUser.current() == null) {
    SyncCredentials myCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword("userid", "pass", false);
    SyncUser syncUser = SyncUser.logIn(myCredentials, AUTH_URL);
}
SyncConfiguration configuration = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(SyncUser.current(), REALM_BASE_URL + "/~/myDB").build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);
```

Then after realm plugin update to version 5.3.1, the **SyncConfiguration.Builder** command got deprecated. It is now suggesting to use **SyncUser.createConfiguration**.
Can I have an example of how to use this command?

I tried using

```
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(SyncUser.current().createConfiguration(REALM_BASE_URL + "/~/myDB").build());
```

However the login wasn't successfull.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to log in first to have a valid SyncUser.

```
    SyncUser user = SyncUser.logIn(SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username, password, true), Constants.AUTH_URL);

    SyncConfiguration config = user.createConfiguration(Constants.USER_REALM).build();
```

So I'm guessing the following would work:

```
SyncUser syncUser = SyncUser.current();
if (syncUser == null) {
    SyncCredentials myCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword("userid", "pass", false);
    syncUser = SyncUser.logIn(myCredentials, AUTH_URL);
}
SyncConfiguration configuration = syncUser.createConfiguration(REALM_BASE_URL + "/~/myDB").build();
```

Note that this defaults to using `partial synchronization`, so if you want to retain previous behavior, you might have to call `.fullSynchronization().build()`.

Comment: Hello, faced the same issue. what about if user lost Internet connection? is it possible to use SyncUser.current() in this case? or I need to logOut()  this user and create the local one? could you please clarify?

Comment: If you are already logged in, then it should work. If you cannot log in, then `logIn` won't succeed.

Comment: If the internet connection is lost the app should load the local realm db file like below

RealmConfiguration realmConfig;
// Create the Realm configuration
realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().assetFile("localDB.realm").build();

Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);


Note that if the user logged successfully atleast once, then subsequent logins will work. However if first login doesn't have internet connection then we need a local db as described above.